# iPhone - Handling two xib's depending on initial orientation

Tags: iphone, orientation

In my application there I'm maintaining two xib files "MyView_Portrait.xib" and "MyView_Landscape.xib" but view controller is same for both. I'm maintaining two xib's because, i want to load respective orientation depending on device orientation or when orientation changes. Also there are many controls in my views and I want to show different images in portrait and landscape views. This is working fine.

But I'm not able to load the appropriate xib when the app starts.
In `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` I'm using the code

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]))
```

to identify the orientation. But its always returning the orientation as landscape. 
How can I achieve the task of loading appropriate view when the app starts up? I'm maintaining two viewcontrollers in the application delegate header file

Answer (score 0):

Check your project's info.plist and make sure you list all 4 supported orientations under the key:

```
Supported interface orientations
```